# How to calculate remaining size of the stack?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, stack-overflow

I recently started to exploit alloca quite a lot, since for caching it is ideal. But my application is based on processing medium chunks of data (say 1024 floats). While assuming the size of stack is say 1MB the chance of overflow is minimal, it would still be handy to be able to determine if there's enough space and sort of optimize:

```
If there's enough space on stack => use stack
else => use dynamic allocation or some other resource
```

So is there a crossplatform way to determine the remaining size of stack?